# re.sub() overrides my string

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm facing a strange behavior with the `re.sub()` function in Python.

In a string, I want to replace all occurences like

```
- list 1
- list 2
```

with HTML code like

```
<li>list 1</li>
<li>list 2</li>
```

So I use

```
text = re.sub('(- (?P<id>.))', '<li>\g<id></li>', text)
```

It works and returns

```
<li>l</li>ist 1
<li>l</li>ist 2
```

Then I add `+` in the regex to match the whole sentence (ie "list 1", "list 2")

```
text = re.sub('(- (?P<id>.+))', '<li>\g<id></li>', text)
```

And suprisingly, it returns

```
</li>ist 1
</li>ist 2
```

The text after `\g<id>` is overriding the left part of the string.

If I try `<li>\g<id>foo` instead it returns `foot 1`

Did you guys already faced this behaviour ?
Is there something I'm missing here ?

Thanks

Comment: Cannot reproduce using neither Python 2.7 nor 3.3. Please include an SSCCE: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Is it possible that you have replaced the leading character in a prior substitution?  What does a print statement just prior to the `re.sub` show?

Comment: Ok it seems i got some Windows linebreaks \r inside the variable "text".
Once i remove all \r occurences in Text before the re.sub(), it works.

I use debian as a Server, and created a small CRUD using BottlePy.

I thought linebreaks inside a textarea (HTML) where interpreted by the server, not the user's OS ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your input file has carriage returns (`'\r'`) at the end of the lines. So, the first input line is like:

```
 - list 1\r\n
```

Since `\r` moves the cursor to the beginning of the current line, and `\n` moves to the beginning of the next line, you can `print` that string and not notice.

After the substitution, your line looks like:

```
<li>list 1\r</li>\n
```

This causes the `</li>` to appear at the beginning of the current line when printed.

You have a couple of possible solutions:

- Strip the `\r` on input
- Exclude `\r` from the character class that you match

An example of the first would be to open the text file with `open(fname, 'rU')`.

An example of the second would be `re.sub('(- (?P<id>[^\r\n]+))', '<li>\g<id></li>', text)`

Comment: It's also possible that the file was opened with a file mode `'rb'` on a Windows platform.  In which case the file mode `'r'` may do the trick.

Comment: Thanks, it was indeed a trailing \r which caused the problem.